# Pmwiki can not acquire lock file

Tags: edit, wiki, pmwiki

When i want to edit a page of my pmwiki, i get a screen containing this message:

```
PmWiki can't process your request
Cannot acquire lockfile
We are sorry for any inconvenience.
More information
Return to http://aim-bigfoot.uzh.ch/~morpho
```

The message in apache's error_log is

```
[Tue Aug 13 12:17:51.969802 2019] [php7:warn] [pid 28521] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:34994] PHP Warning:  fopen(wiki.d/.flock): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /server2/home/morpho/public_html/wiki/pmwiki.php on line 579, referer: http://server1.loc.ch/~morpho/
```

If i delete .flock, and try again, the same error is reported.
This happens for all pages in this particular pmwiki.

The permissions for the wiki.d directory

```
drwxrwxrwx. 2 morpho morpho 4096 Aug 13 12:17 /server2/home/morpho/public_html/pmwiki/wiki.d/
```

The security context for this directory:

```
drwxrwxrwx. morpho morpho unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 /server2/home/morpho/public_html/pmwiki/wiki.d/
```

If i disable SELinux with `sudo setenforce 0`, the page can be edited.

I have a second pmwiki system with the same permissions and security contexts, differing only in the user name, where editing is not a problem.

How can i make this pmwiki editable (with enforced SELinux)?

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about PmWiki engine, it is about PHP writing permission on your server. The problem is that PHP is unable to create files in /wiki.d and probably other directories.

To point the problem, you can create simple php-script like:

```
<?php
    touch( __DIR__ . '/test.file' );
?>
```

When executed, it should create file /test.file  , but on your server this will not work, and this is a real problem to solve.

I suggest asking your hosting provider support for help to solve this problem.